# Xamarin Tools->Android menu disabled in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio, xamarin

As in the title, I cannot use Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, because I have Tools > Android menu disabled. Has anyone got the same issue? I was trying to figure out what the problem is and find the solution for hours, but nothing like reinstalling Visual Studio or installing Android Studio and later launching the Visual Studio helps.

Comment: Can you attach your IDE logs to your question? Secondly, are you within a Xamarin.Android project when you're trying to go to `Tools > Android`? https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs

Answer (score 0):

the solution to solve this problem :

- to launch uninstaller.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
- then to do a manual installation
  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Now it is OK, the sub menus under Tools / Android are active.

@moderator:
yesterday I put my IDE logs as Jon Douglas asked because I had the same issue and now this post is not here. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is :
1) Uninstall Android SDK Manager C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
(Wait till the Uninstall completes...it will take some time complete...so wait)
2) Open Visual Studio 2015 Community Installer, scroll down and click the CheckBox for Android SDK Manager, Visual Studio then automatically installs the Android SDK Manager.
[Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzEfH.png)